# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, regex, typeerror, undefined-function

I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for the following code:

```
var jay = /^(\/gallery\/P[\w\dåäö\/]+)$/;
if(window.location.pathname.test(jay)) {  // It complains about this line
    alert(2);
}
```

`console.log(window.location.pathname)` prints `/gallery/P1290574/%C3%A4ndra`. The file is encoded in UTF-8. In the address bar it says `/gallery/P1290574/ändra`. When I run the regex on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) against `/gallery/P1290574/ändra`, it works like a charm but not on my website.

What have I missed? Do I have to change the regex so it can identify `%C3%A4` too?

Comment: You've missed that `.test()` is not a string method.

Comment: So I must use a variable for `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: What @Juhana means is that it should be `jay.test(window.location.pathname)`

Comment: Oh! I didn't noticed that when I Googled :P Many thanks, Pointy and Juhana

Comment: In general "undefined is not a function" literally means that (in this case) `.test` is undefined (i.e. doesn't exist) and you're trying to call it as if it were a function. You can never get that error if the method exists but the parameter is wrong.

Comment: Also, you can never fix an "undefined is not a function" error by just assigning the value to another variable because that new variable would have the exact same methods as the original variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var jay = /^(\/gallery\/P[\w\dåäö\/]+)$/;
if(jay.test(window.location.pathname)) {
    alert(2);
}
```

You've got the syntax of `.test()` backwards. It goes like this:

```
regex.test(variable);
```